# How do I handle indexOf returning 'null' without using try/catch(err)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I'm populating a table with data - using `fixed-data-table`, which is  a React.js component. However, that isn't so important at this stage.

The table has a search box where the issue stems from.

First, here's the interesting part of the code.

```
for (var index = 0; index < size; index++) {
            if (!filterBy || filterBy == undefined) {
                filteredIndexes.push(index);
            }
            else {

                var backendInfo = this._dataList[index];

                var userListMap = hostInfo.userList;

                var userListArr = Object.values(userListMap);


                function checkUsers(){
                    for (var key in userListArr) {
                        if (userListArr.hasOwnProperty(key) && userListArr[key].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }


                if (backendInfo.firstName.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1 || backendInfo.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1 || backendInfo.countryOrigin.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1
                    || backendInfo.userListMap.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) {
                    filteredIndexes.push(index);
                }

            }
        }
```

This is rendered and the last part is throwing errors if you input something in the table, and a column returns `null` from the user input.

The thing is, I can make the code work if I change the last part to ..

```
        try {
            if (backendInfo.firstName.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1 || backendInfo.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1 ||    backendInfo.countryOrigin.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1
            || backendInfo.userListMap.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) {
            filteredIndexes.push(index);
            }
        }
        catch(err) {
            console.log('Exception')
        }
```

With the try/catch, it works 100% as intended and handles the indexOf returning null... But this can't be the way to properly handle it - I'm assuming this sort of exception handling is, well, supposed to be for rare exceptions, and shouldn't really be used on the front-end as much as the backend.

How do I handle indexOf returning null in the above Javascript code? It might return null in any of the sources columns that are being populated.

Comment: indexOf should return eighter `-1` or any index, never null. If it throws an error, it is not because it returns null. Can you make this work in a snippet with sample data?

Comment: `indexOf` will never return `null` when run on an array; one of your preceding variables (`backendInfo` or one of its properties) must be the culprit. What is the exact error text you get?

Comment: Ah sorry. I have phrased myself poorly. The input data might have a key whose value is null. That's what I meant. The error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null`

Comment: So is the error something like `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"`? That would make a difference

Comment: @Randy I just put the error above - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null`

Comment: @DomeTune this might be something that could occur in any cell of the table, so throwing an exception isn't really best practice I think?

Comment: Is `backendInfo.userListMap` null, since you're trying to call `indexOf` on null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a key cannot be found, JS will throw an error. `Try-catch` is a good way to fix these errors, but there is an alternative:

You could check if keys exist in an object prior to pushing a value into it.

```js
var data = { };

var key = "test";

// your method works great
try {
  var value = data.firstname.indexOf(key);
} catch (err) {}

// another method, I'd prefer the try/catch
var value = data.firstname ? data.firstname.indexOf(key) : undefined;


// test if the object is the type of object you are looking for
// this is in my opinion the best option.
if(data.firstname instanceof Array){
  var value = data.firstname.indexOf(key);
}


// you can use the last option in your code like this:

var firstnameHasKey = data.firstname instanceof Array && ~data.firstname.indexOf(key);
var lastnameHasKey = data.lastname instanceof Array && ~data.lastname.indexOf(key);
if(firstnameHasKey || lastnameHasKey){
  // logics
}
```

If you test the `instanceof` && `indexOf`, there will never be an error. If `firstname` is `undefined`, the `indexOf` will never be checked.

Ofcourse you can use this for other types:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate instanceof Date;     // returns true
myDate instanceof Object;   // returns true
myDate instanceof String;   // returns false
```

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: I tried implementing the whole thing in one if sentence; It doesn't throw errors but the search functionality is way off. I'll try creating variables like you suggest.

Comment: @cbll The only thing you have to change, is to check if the `instanceof` is set correct. That should not change the results, just prevent errors. I had `firstnameHasKey && lastnameHasKey` by accident, that should obviously be `firstnameHasKey || lasthameHasKey`.

Comment: But we should still check if indexOf doesn't return -1 though?

Comment: I tried it but the searches are still not working as they were with the try/except :/

Comment: Try to make a jsfiddle or snippet that runs, and I'll see what I can do for you.

Comment: It's strange, some columns it can search just fine in, others not at all. I suspect there's another issue. I think it would take a long time to reproduce something like this in a jsfiddle, but i'll consider it.

Comment: Good news is - the column which has a null works in terms of search. Bad news, two other columns won't return respond to the search at all, but they did before. Hmm.

Comment: Small sketch here, but it doesn't do much yet, but it shows what I've tried at least. https://jsfiddle.net/u6tLj3yb/

Comment: In that jsfiddle, columns checkUsers and countryOrigin are the only ones actually working as intended :/